# My function doesn't work ( weekend days)

Tags: javascript, html, function

Can someone help me out with this? It needs to return a yes when filled in Friday, Saturday or Sunday and in all other cases a No.
Every time it ends up in "JA"....

code:

```
    // Nieuwe Array aanmaken dagen
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Zondag","Maandag","Dinsdag","Woensdag","Donderdag","Vrijdag","Zaterdag"];
d.getDay();

// Prompt welke dag
var dag = prompt('Welke dag is het vandaag?');

//functies

function isHetAlWeekend (days, dag)
{
    if ( dag === days[0] || dag === days[5])
    {
        console.log('JA');
    }
    else
    {   
        console.log('NEE');
    }

}
```

Comment: `Friday, Saturday or Sunday` I only see two days in the condition of the `JA` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, test `Zondag`, `Vrijdag` or `Zaterdag`, you will get `JA`, otherwise `NEE`

```js
    // Nieuwe Array aanmaken dagen
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Zondag","Maandag","Dinsdag","Woensdag","Donderdag","Vrijdag","Zaterdag"];
d.getDay();

// Prompt welke dag
var dag = prompt('Welke dag is het vandaag?');

//functies

function isHetAlWeekend (days, dag)
{
    if ( dag === days[0] || dag === days[5] || dag === days[6])
    {
        alert('JA');
    }
    else
    {   
        alert('NEE');
    }

}

isHetAlWeekend(days, dag);
```

Comment: Wow It did work actually. I forget to call my function -.- Thanks anyways!!